# Extract Author Name and Abstract from python Code

Tags: python, data-extraction, google-scholar

In my python project, I've list of cited papers and for each paper, I need its `Author Name` and `Abstract` and `Citation Count` from **google scholars** . I was using [scholarly . PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/scholarly/) like this :

```
search_pub = scholarly.search_pubs(paperName)
docInfo = next(search_pub)
```

but now I'm getting this error:

> Exception: Cannot fetch the page from Google Scholar.

It seems like they've blocked my IP due to multiple requests. Now I'm unable to find any other programmatic way to extract these info. I can have a list of paper references to extract data for.

Can anyone help me out with any python library or guide me to write some piece of code for this?

Comment: Bypassing rate limiters is not the kind of help stack overflow will provide.

Answer (score 1):

You can just wait for this temporary ban to expire and keep going. Make sure to insert a `time.sleep(...)` or similar in your code to stay under their rate limit. Google Scholar has no official API, so scraping is your only option if this is the data you want.

(I am not recommending that you scrape, and please note that Google Scholar disallows robots through [their robots.txt](https://www.google.com/robots.txt))

Comment: Sorry, what does it mean by *disallows robots through*??

Comment: I am not a lawyer and cannot really advise you on this. What I do know is that my answer is correct; you will only be banned for an hour or so, and you can then resume crawling so long as you don't trip the limit again. If my down-voter has more information they are welcome to share.

Comment: @NullPointer the robots.txt file specifies the rules it want scrapers to follow; the Google scholar robots.txt specifies that scraping is not allowed meaning that they don't like it. Whether these rules can also be enfored by legal action is up for debate, and might also depend on your local jurisdiction

Answer (score 0):

Google Scholar blocks your IP if you query too much or too often. Even if you make your program sleep, do not make it sleep periodically since they can detect that too. Google considers this as DoS (Denial of Service) attack. Even if you randomise your sleep time, at one point, if you make too many queries, it will flag you. One workaround for this is using rotating proxy services. Look up online, there are plenty of free ones. They offer you User-Agent strings, which if you put randomly for every query you make, you're good to go afaik.

Comment: I already tried that approach, but that also didn't work for me.